Error rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html" on NGINX even when I have index.html in root directory
I'm facing "rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html"" error in NGINX even when I have index.html in my root directory already.
Here is how I set things up:
-I cloned my UI repository and stored in /var/www/yourfrontend/ProjectJ_UI with node_modules, package-lock.json, package.json, public, src files and folders.
-I run $npm run build on the directory containing the package.json to create a build folder with index.html file
-After that, in my NGINX configuration, I wrote the following code:
# HTTP configuration (redirect to HTTPS)
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name avery-insights.icu www.avery-insights.icu;

    # Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS configuration
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name avery-insights.icu www.avery-insights.icu;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl-key/avery-insights.icu.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl-key/avery-insights.icu.key;

    # SSL settings (adjust as needed)
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # Backend configuration for Node.js
    location /node/ {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    # Backend configuration for Flask
    location /flask/ {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:7000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    root /var/www/yourfrontend/ProjectJ_UI/build;
    index index.html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    location /static/ {
        expires 1y;
        add_header Cache-Control "build";
    }
}

And I got  rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html" in sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
Edit: I checked other posts around the internet for this issue and people said to put the =404 after the try_files but that's for only when I don't have the index.html in my root directory, right? In my case all things set up unless I missed something here.
Please help and thanks in advance.

You don't have index.html in /var/www/yourfrontend/ProjectJ_UI/build.
